# Find if three 2D points are collinear but not collinear with origin

Tags: calculus

Pretty much what the title says, given three 2D points different from (0,0), i want to know if this points are collinear, with the origin not being part of the line the form.

Comment: If the three points are collinear, then pick any two and decide if these two are collinear with the origin.

Comment: " i want to know if this points are collinear, with the origin not being part of the line the form" - what does this mean?

Comment: Hint: Put the points on the plane $z=1$. What’s the volume of the paralellepiped defined by these points and the 3-D origin if they are colinear?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Take a point $(x,y)$ among the three where $x\neq0$. If there is none they are co-linear together with the origin (Return False).  Compute $k=y/x$. Compute the differences $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ of the other two points with the point $(x,y)$. If $x_1=x_2=0$ return True. If $x_1=0\neq x_2$ or $x_1\neq0=x_2$ return False. Compute $k_1=y_1/x_1$ and $k_2=y_2/x_1$. If $k_1=k_2\neq k$ return True, otherwise return False.

Comment: If you are implementing this test, you should definitely not use Bernard's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a direct answer if we embed the affine plane in the projective plane: the points $(x,y)$, $(x',y')$, $(x'',y'')$ are collinear if and only if their images in the projective plane by the canonical embedding $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y,1)$ are, which is true if and only if the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}x&x'&x''\\y&y'&y''\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0$$
They're *not* collinear with the origin  if the determinants $\begin{vmatrix}x&x'&0\\y&y'&0\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}$ and the like, are *not* $0$, which means $\begin{vmatrix}x&x'\\y&y'\end{vmatrix}\ne 0$. In other words the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}x&x'&x''\\y&y'&y''\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
must have rank $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just find the line through two of them and then see whether the third point is on that line? It's even easier to decide whether the origin is on the line.

Answer (score 1):

Move the three points such that one of the points is at the origin. Now you have to determine whether two points and the origin is collinear, which is just checking whether the coordinates of the two points are in ratio.

Answer (score 0):

To see if the three points are collinear,
compute the area of the
triangle they form.
If they are collinear,
the area is zero.

The  formula is
$ x_1y_2 + x_2y_3 + x_3y_1 – x_1y_3 – x_2y_1 – x_3y_2
$.

If they are collinear,
the equation of the line
through the first two is
$\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}
=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$.
If this passes through the origin,
then
$\frac{y_1}{x_1}
=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$.